# Nested (Condition) ? true:false statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization, conditional-statements

In the following code snippet,

```
var paintMode = data.hasOwnProperty('regions') ?
        'regions' : data.hasOwnProperty('vpcs') ?
        'vpcs' : data.hasOwnProperty('zones') ? 
        'zones' : data.hasOwnProperty('subnets') ? 
        'subnets' : data.hasOwnProperty('clusters') ? 'clusters' : null;
```

I've used a deeply nested `(condition) ? true : false` -- is this acceptable? is it optimized? If its bad is there an alternative?

It is used inside a recursive function which does a few SVG operations, here's the function snippet if you are curious.

```
function paintGroups(data) {
    var paintMode = data.hasOwnProperty('regions') ? 'regions' : data.hasOwnProperty('vpcs') ? 'vpcs' : data.hasOwnProperty('zones') ? 'zones' : data.hasOwnProperty('subnets') ? 'subnets' : data.hasOwnProperty('clusters') ? 'clusters' : null,
        depth = data[paintMode].length,
        i,
        Shape; //= raphealObj.rect();

    // Register stacking order
    // Paint a shape with styles based on paintMode
    // Store its id & Label for other ops.

    if(paintMode) {
        for(i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            paintGroups(data[paintMode][i]);
        }
    }

    // to reverse the order of paint - place your statements here
}
```

Comment: Assuming none of these are "falsey" values (`false`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`), it might be more readable and maintainable to use a cascading OR statement: `var paintMode = data.regions || data.vpcs ...`, in both cases the performance is negligible.

Comment: So `var paintData = data.regions || data.vpcs ...` hmmm, its an option. If i tweak the rest of my program logic i can get away with this.

Comment: Its a network hierarchy, Virtual Machines, Firewalls & Storage `inside` Clusters `inside` Subnets `inside` Zones `inside` Virtual Private Clouds `inside` Regions. Something to do with AWS.
The last node of the tree can be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking using binary operations should be faster than conditional statements with branching because of branch prediction, caching, yada yada yada. But your code is fine. I like the && || but it's just a preference and not based on anything empirical.

```
var data = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var result = data.x || 
    data.y && "y" || 
    data.z && "z" || 
    data.w && "w" ||
    null;
```

I didn't feel like typing .hasOwnProperty.

**EDIT After actually looking at your code**

```
var paintMode = data.regions || data.vpcs || data.zones || data.subnets || data.clusters || null;
if(paintNode) {
    for(var i=0; i<paintMode.length; i++)
        paintGroups(paintMode[i]);
}
```

Comment: Just ran your code through my console, Looks good and more readable as @jbabey suggested.